# C++: Queue of custom data type vector error

Tags: c++, vector, queue

I am using a thread-safe queue of custom type vector. it shows the following error. I am not sure what I am missing here.

> Error  C2664   'std::vector>::vector(std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &&,const _Alloc &) noexcept()': cannot convert argument 2 from 'int' to 'const std::allocator<_Ty> &'<A>.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

template<typename T>
class threadsafe_queue
{
private:
    mutable std::mutex mut;
    std::queue<T> data_queue;
    std::condition_variable data_cond;
public:
    threadsafe_queue()
    {}
    threadsafe_queue(threadsafe_queue const& other)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(other.mut);
        data_queue = other.data_queue;
    }

    void push(T new_value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_queue.push(new_value);
        data_cond.notify_one();
    }

    void wait_and_pop(T& value)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lk, [this] {return !data_queue.empty(); });
        value = data_queue.front();
        data_queue.pop();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> wait_and_pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lk, [this] {return !data_queue.empty(); });
        std::shared_ptr<T> res(std::make_shared<T>(data_queue.front()));
        data_queue.pop();
        return res;
    }

    bool try_pop(T& value)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        if (data_queue.empty)
             return false;
        value = data_queue.front();
        data_queue.pop();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> try_pop()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        if (data_queue.empty())
            return std::shared_ptr<T>();
        std::shared_ptr<T> res(std::make_shared<T>(data_queue.front()));
        data_queue.pop();
        return res;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        return data_queue.empty();
    }
};

class cp_data
{
public:
    int num;
    double time;
    cp_data(int a, double b)
    {
        num = a;
        time = b;
    }
};

int main() {

    std::vector<cp_data> data(1,2);
    threadsafe_queue<std::vector<cp_data>> temp_queue;
    temp_queue.push(data);
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no constructor for vector which forwards its arguments on to the data type it is holding for creation of a single element.

However, you can use the `std::initializer_list` constructor to pass in an object (or more than one if you'd like) by doing this:

Change

```
std::vector<cp_data> data(1,2);
```

to

```
std::vector<cp_data> data{{1,2}};
```

Alternatively you could be more syntactically explicit about creating the `cp_data` object:

```
std::vector<cp_data> data{cp_data(1,2)};
```

`{1,2}` creates the `cp_data` object then the object is passed in to the vector's constructor via the `std::initializater_list` created by the outer `{...}`'s

live: https://godbolt.org/g/s2AwJU

As a side note, `vector::emplace_back` does work like how your code is trying to construct an object - it will forward your arguments to the constructor of `cp_data` in order to create an object to store in the vector.

Comment: Suggested change shows the following error. > C2398 Element '1': conversion from 'int' to 'const unsigned __int64' requires a narrowing conversion thread &lt;A>.

Comment: @ZeeshanHayat what compiler are you using?  this answer works on clang/gcc/msvc on godbolt.  https://godbolt.org/g/YVFTMo

Comment: I provided another syntax for doing the same thing in the answer.